# What is signature of a Slider's callback function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The documentation page for Unity's Slider class (as of version 2021.3, which appears to be the latest version of this documentation) can be found here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.Slider.html

This documentation does not give the one critical piece of information that, it seems to me, every potential user of the Slider class needs to know: the signature of its callback function.

One might guess that the callback signature was documented in the documentation for the Slider's RegisterCallback() function, but it is not. (See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.RegisterCallback.html.)

I assume that I am much stupider than the people who wrote this documentation, and therefore that the signature of the callback ***is*** documented somewhere else in Unity's official, up-to-date documentation.

I am NOT asking for third-party tutorials that may or may not be out of date, or which present some approach that may or may not break the next time Unity is updated. I am looking for Unity's official documentation of this callback's signature.

Where can I find the **official** documentation of this crucial factoid?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-Change-Events.html

Comment: Too much emotions for a technical question

Comment: @MitchWheat: Thank you for your answer. It is the reply that comes the closest to answering my post's stated question. The page at that the URL that you kindly provided documents the signature of a callback for booleans. From this, I can infer what the signature would be for non-boolean types, even though that is not explicitly documented. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @BoppityBop: I apologize for allowing my emotions to show in my technical question. I have tried to encapsulate my immense frustration with Unity's new Input System. However, sometimes,  no matter how one tries to enforce data hiding, ones interface exposes ones internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can peek at the Unity source code [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference), and solve all your questions about signatures.

About Slider,
In the same [Unity's documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.Slider.html) page that you shared, you can see that the method `RegisterCallback` is under the grouper "Inherited Members". Inherited from whom? Well, at the top of the page, you can see in the inheritance breadcrumb "Inherits from:UIElements.BaseSlider_1", which is a link to the parent class. If you keep following up the inheritance chain, you will end up at the class [`CallbackEventHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.html), which is where `RegisterCallback` is originally declared.

In the [github page](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Events/EventHandler.cs) for `CallbackEventHandler`, you can see that there are a few overloads for that method:

```
public void RegisterCallback<TEventType>(
  EventCallback<TEventType> callback, TrickleDown useTrickleDown = TrickleDown.NoTrickleDown
) where TEventType : EventBase<TEventType>, new()
    
public void RegisterCallback<TEventType, TUserArgsType>(
  EventCallback<TEventType, TUserArgsType> callback, TUserArgsType userArgs, TrickleDown useTrickleDown = TrickleDown.NoTrickleDown
) where TEventType : EventBase<TEventType>, new()
```

The interesting parameter here is `callback`, that can be either  `EventCallback<TEventType>` (for events without arguments) or `EventCallback<TEventType, TUserArgsType>` (for events with arguments), where `TEventType` is `EventBase`.

[`EventCallback`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Events/EventCallback.cs) itself is a delegate:

```
public delegate void EventCallback<in TEventType>(TEventType evt)
public delegate void EventCallback<in TEventType, in TCallbackArgs>(TEventType evt, TCallbackArgs userArgs)
```

And [`EventBase`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/ModuleOverrides/com.unity.ui/Core/Events/EventBase.cs) is the base class for all UIElements events, which are the events that you can ultimately register with the method `RegisterCallback`. You can find the reference of available events in the "Event Reference" [documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-Events-Reference.html).

Specifically to Slider, you will probably be most interested in the [`ChangeEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/UIE-Change-Events.html). Interestingly, because `Slider` implements `INotifyValueChange<T>`, you'd better register your callback using `RegisterValueChangedCallback` instead of `RegisterCallback`. Something like this:

```
slider.RegisterValueChangedCallback(v => {
  var oldValue = v.previousValue;
  var newValue = v.newValue; 
  // (...) whatever your logic here
});
```

Comment: Saying "Refer to the source code, here" has the unparalleled virtue of generality -- it is, ultimately, the answer to all questions. I was not previously aware that Unity's source code was publicly available.  With this answer, I should be able to avoid troubling this forum with any similar questions. Thanks!  :-)